# Is there anyway to run robot framework without a .robot/.txt script, or can I generate .robot/.txt file from some data?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, robotframework, rpa

Is there any way to run robot framework with a code or json instead of .robot file? Or should I generate a .robot file first and then run? I am unsure if there is a better way to do this, since some of the steps depend on previous steps' output (unittest/pytest does not support this).

I have a list of test sequences in json, for example

```
{
"seq_id": 1,
"seq_type": 1,  # normal, flag
"seq_len": 1,  # 1 for normal, n for flag
"flag_data": {
    "flag_name": "",
    "flag_type": "", # if/else, for, while with steps block
    "flag_length": 1,

    # flag_type-if
    "mid_val": 1,  # variable
    "comparison_left_type": '>',  # > >= empty
    "comparison_left_var": 1,  # variable or constant
    "comparison_right_type": '<',  # > >= empty
    "comparison_right_var": 1,  # variable or constant

    # flag_type-else

    # flag_type-for
    "loop_length": 1,  # variable or constant
    
    # flag_type-while
    # "mid_val": 1,  # variable
    # "comparison_left_type": '>',  # > >= empty
    # "comparison_left_var": 1,  # variable or constant
    # "comparison_right_type": '<',  # > >= empty
    # "comparison_right_var": 1,  # variable or constant
},

"sequence_data": [{
    "step_name": 'step_1',
    "step_type": '', # a embedded function to be used in function library
    "step_variable_a": a
    "step_variable_b": b
}]
```

}

Comment: can you compile a java program with a json isntead of code? The same is valid for robot framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run Robot Framework but not in .robot file, you can run in Python instead.

Or if you want to read this json file, you can create a function in Python or search a Library Json in Robot Framework to use for read this json file and transform in dictionary to work whit the information inside of your json file.

A example of read and transform this json file in dictionary in Python:

```py
def json_to_dict(YOUR_JSON_PATH):
    try:
        with open(YOUR_JSON_PATH) as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file) 
        return data
    except Exception as err:
        return err
```

You cannot run a json file like .py or .robot archives, because .json files is made to use for information.